# How to use Docker's moby to create a custom made container system?

Tags: docker, containers, moby

Docker/Moby announced the [17.06 CE](https://blog.docker.com/2017/06/announcing-docker-17-06-community-edition-ce/) release today, however it's not clear to me how they actually crafted the 17.06 using moby.

There isn't 17.06 branch on the [docker/moby](https://github.com/moby/moby) github project, likewise no information on their moby project [website](http://mobyproject.org/).

They have the following depiction, but how to actually achieve such architecture isn't clear.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things going on here, both with the name "Moby".

> Docker/Moby announced the 17.06 CE release today, however it's not clear to me how they crafted the 17.06 using moby.

This comes from the [docker/docker-ce](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce) repo where they effectively vendor in pieces of [moby/moby](https://github.com/moby/moby) and other components in the components.conf file.

> There isn't 17.06 branch on the docker/moby github project, likewise no explanation appears on their moby project website.

That should be [moby/moby](https://github.com/moby/moby) and the branches there are historical from the prior location in [docker/docker](https://github.com/docker/docker) (which now redirects).

> They have the following depiction, but how to chop or add a new component isn't clear.

This is where the Moby names get a bit confusing. The container engine formerly found at docker/docker was moved to moby/moby. Moby is also a project that acts as a landing space for everything Docker is giving to the community. And Moby is lastly part of a new OS project from the [LinuxKit](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit) team that can create lightweight container based operating systems. The picture you shared is discussing the latter project where it's easy to extend that OS with your own components.

> For example I would love to remove the Secret Management component to see how easy and modular moby is.

This gets into a longer range goal of Docker. They plan to redesign the engine and break of the monolith that has become the container engine. The goal is to turn the engine into a gRPC proxy that integrates with all the other components like libnetwork, swarmkit, etc. However, this is still coming out of the design stage. What already exists is the ability to add additional components in the OS based on the LinuxKit work, and of course all the source code is there in moby/moby along with docker/docker-ce for you to fork the code and create your own engine.

For more details, I've also written a [blog post](https://boxboat.com/2017/05/12/moby-inception/) on the topic that goes into the different names and what's happening with them.

Comment: I'm watching this one from the outside like you, but my gut says that getting the monolith broken up will take months. Maybe 17.09, but wouldn't be surprised if that's more like 17.12 before they finish.

Comment: Docker started from the community pulling that fully functioning project out of dotCloud. Moby is taking the reverse approach, giving the code to the community to work while it's still being developed.